# Play Framework 2.1 + ReactiveMongo - populate multiple drop-down lists

Tags: scala, mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have a form with multiple drop-down lists that I create with `select` and `options` helpers in a template. Entities that should populate the lists are taken from the database. However, the retrieval from the database is asynchronous, so I should use `Async` in the action, as in this [example](http://stephane.godbillon.com/2012/10/18/writing-a-simple-app-with-reactivemongo-and-play-framework-pt-1.html). However, in my case, there is not a single `find` operation that I should wait on, but a `Seq` of `Future` objects, of unknown size. So how can I wait on multiple `Future`-s to prepare the lists before rendering the page? Or maybe there is some better way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala futures would worth nothing if you wouldn't have a nice way to combine them.

If you have a sequence of future objects you can transform it into a future of sequence:

```
val futureList = Future.sequence(listOfFutures)
```

So now you have a single future to deal with. See the docs on [Future companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$) for a few other useful functions to combine futures in various ways.

If you're curious about other ways to play with futures (e.g. you can even combine them using a simple for-comprehansion due to their monadic nature) you might want to take a look at [the primer on Scala futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/futures.html) for more insights.

Also if you're working with ReactiveMongo it would be definitely worth to take a look at the [docs on Enumerator/Iteratee implementation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/Iteratees) of Play 2.x. If you master that approach you will be able to do real magic combining your reactive data streams on the fly and much more.

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough answer!